# Adding filter functions in place of a literal expression in GeoTools?

Tags: java, geotools, filter, cql

I'm writing some code to use filter functions in geotools.

`(attName >= replacementFunc() AND title LIKE replacementFunc()) AND attName2 = replacementFunc()`

In the area that says `LIKE` I get a parsing error. If I change it to `EQ` there are no problems. If I wrap it in quotes, then I get a literal `'replacementFunc()'` inside the output. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

In the CQL grammar `Like` is expected to take a String Literal. Alternatively, you could modify the grammar to take an expression (which is what a function is).

You can probably build this using the `FilterFactory` directly.